# pgRoutingLayer does not show the database connected

Tags: qgis, pgrouting

pgRoutingLayer does not show the database connected.

QGIS: 2.14.15 and pgAdmin III

CREATE EXTENSION postgis; (ok)

CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting; (ok)

SELECT pgr_version(); (2.0.0,pgrouting-2.0.0,0,d6ed2cb,master,1.53.0) (ok)

[image: DB Manager]

[image: pgAdmin III]

[image: pgRoutin]

[image: DB Manager tables]

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you configure the database connection in QGIS?
Can you see your data?

Comment: I think I followed all the steps to complete the creation and connection of the database (teste_01), both in pdAdmin III and in QGIS. Please see the figures added. I can see the data.

Comment: You don't have a QGIS database connection, it seems. This is not a pgRouting issue. First try to show your road network as a PostGIS layer in QGIS. If that works, then proceed with the pgrouting plugin.

Comment: I think I have a connection to the test_01 database because when I right click on (DB Manager) newark_splited_1, newark_splitted_1_vertices_pgr, and students, and then,  I click Add to Canvas all of them are shown as layers in QGIS, as you can see above. However the database test_01 still does not appear in the pgRouting panel. More information: I created and saved a project in QGIS with these layers. When I reload this project in QGIS, the name and password of the database are asked.

Comment: QGIS 2.14.15 was replaced by QGIS 2.14.18 (deleting user\me\.qgis2 and the registry entries for QGIS, by running the regedit program). But the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The database connection users and password must be

- saved
- saved as 'basic' --> Not as a configuration

[image: Save your password]